# How does Action<T,T,T> work?

Tags: c#, abstraction

I'm trying to figure out how to properly use an Action delegate that takes more than one (through ten) type arguments like so:

`Action<T,T,T>` for example.

Let's say I'm using the following function prototype:

`public void SomeFunc(Action<bool, int> foo)`

How would I go about passing a boolean and an integer value to foo when calling that function? Maybe I'm just getting this entire thing wrong, but when looking it up on MSDN and other sources I just can't get my head around how this thing actually works. Same for its `Func<TReturn, T, T>` counterpart.

MSDN comes up with some pretty incomprehensible examples, and I'm hoping someone here can actually show me an example of how these delegates are implemented properly. Thanks.

Comment: With `Func`, the order is the other way around: [`Func<T1, T2, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) like this:

```
SomeFunc( (a1, a2) => {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("params: {0}, {1}", a1, a2));
});
```

Or, if you already have a function that matches the delegate, you can pass it directly.

```
void SomeFunc(Action<bool,int> foo)
{
    foo(true, 99);
    // stuff
}

void matchesDelegate(bool a1, int a2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("params: {0}, {1}", a1, a2));
}

SomeFunc(matchesDelegate);
```

*Outputs*:

> params: true, 99

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks ... "anonymous method" is I guess what I was thinking of.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

With a signature like:

```
public void SomeFunc(Action<bool, int> foo)
```

You call `SomeFunc` and pass in only one parameter - an action that takes two parameters. Think of the action as a **callback** method as that is what it really is. Somewhere in the `SomeFunc` method it will call `foo` and pass in the parameters there. You don't need to supply them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`Action` and `Func` delegates work just like any other.  The simple `Action` delegate looks basically like:

```
public delegate void Action();
```

and is called like so:

```
public void doAction(Action foo)
{
    Action(); // You call the action here.
}
```

Using generic arguments, the definition basically looks like:

```
public delegate void Action(T1, T2, T3);
```

and is called like the following to pass parameters into the Action:

```
public void SomeFunc(Action<bool,int> foo)
{
    bool param1 = true;
    int param2 = 69;
    foo(param1, param2); // Here you are calling the foo delegate.
}
```

Just like other delegates, these delegates can be assigned with explicitly defined functions,

```
public void AnAction()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}

doAction(AnAction);
```

or with anonymous functions.

```
Action<bool,int> anonymousAction = (b,i) =>
{
    if (b == true && i > 5)
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
}
SomeFunc(anonymousAction);
```

Answer (score 1):

If foo is `Action<bool, t>` you can call it with `foo(true, 42)`

If you want to call SomeFunc, you can call it with a method:

```
SomeFunc(MyMethod);
```

where you have:

```
public void MyMethod(bool b, int i){}
```

Or you can call it with an anonymous method:

```
SomeFunc(delegate(bool b, int i) {Trace.WriteLine(b); Trace.WriteLine(i);});
```

Or you can call it with a lambda:

```
someFunc((b,i) => {Trace.WriteLine(b); Trace.WriteLine(i);});
```